# Expand Image to container width when moving to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to make the width of the image, when it transitions into another line to take up as much room as possible?

For example, if the images are displayed next to each other, as soon as one of them drops to the next line, that image on the next line expands to container's width.

I believe I saw this being achieved with flexbox but I can't remember how to do it and if there's alternate ways to do it, I'm all ears.

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/6kpyhpbh/

```css
body,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.grid img{

  float:left;
  height:100px;

}
.grid{
    display:flex;  flex-grow:2;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex:1` to the image.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6kpyhpbh/1/)

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-grow: 2;   <-- can be removed; not doing anything; applies only to flex items */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid img {
  /* float: left;    <-- can be removed; floats are ignored in a flex container */
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;           /* NEW; tells flex items to distribute available space evenly; 
                        a single flex item on the line will consume 100% of the space;
                        two flex items will take 50% each; etc. */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much, side question, what if you only wanted this flex:1 to happen to everything after the first row, this is what I tried, but it isn't perfect, it only selects the first element not the first row:  https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/osk0yqec/1/

Comment: So you want to target all items once they wrap to the second row but not before. I'm not sure this is possible in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to `.grid img`

```
flex-basis: 25%;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

`flex-basis: 25%` will let only 4 images / line

`flex-grow: 1` will try to grow the images on the line to the div boundaries

`width: 100%; height: 100%;` will keep the image aspect ratio

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kpyhpbh/3/)